# MySQL REGEXP not matching with 2 commas

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a result like this below.

```
212.212.212.212, 
212.212.212.211, 
212.212.212.213, 10.16.10.10, 
212.212.212.215,
```

How can i just select only

```
212.212.212.213, 
212.212.212.213, 
212.212.212.215,
```

with mysql regexp ?

```
select numbers from table where numbers REGEXP ', $'
```

That gives all.

Not: there is space after each comma.

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between the data set and the result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select numbers from table where numbers REGEXP '^[^,]+, $'
```

But really, you should not store comma-separated values in a database table in the first place.

Comment: Yes i know i don't store like that generally. This is a temporary table i should filter some value. Thank you.

Comment: could you explain the regexp here please? That i should understand.

Comment: `^` - start of string, `[^,]+` any character except a comma, multiple times, `, $` a comma and the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
select numbers from table where numbers REGEXP '^[^,]+, $'
```

@Tomalak You're very right